# Websocket client.send() inside a express GET handler

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I am following [this](http://mherman.org/blog/2016/03/13/designing-a-restful-api-with-node-and-postgres/#.WgH631uCypo) method to develop a postgresql+express+websocket based nodejs API server. After one of  the GET calls are completed, it needs to send a message to a websocket client.

Once the db insert is complete I am calling the following function using the next() middleware call:

```
WsBroker.prototype.notifydevices = function(req, res, next) {
    devices.forEach(function each(client) {
      console.log("Sending to  client list")
      client.send(res.locals.notificationmessage);

    })
};
```

Here "devices" is a list of current websocket connections.This is how I am preparing it:

```
var devices = [];
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {
          devices.push(ws)
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

I understand that "client.send()" is using the same "res" object as the express API handler. Thats why this error is coming. How can I force the websocket client to not use the "res" object?

Comment: Is it?  Where is `client` defined?  Shouldn't it be a `WebSocket` object?  And `client` isn't mentioned at all in the tutorial you linked when I searched the page.

Comment: @zero298  Websocket is my addition. Updated question for clarity

Comment: I'm still not clear.  The code that you have presented so far should not be causing the error that you are seeing.  What line is generating that error?  Have you tried stepping through your code using the [node debugger](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/)?  Use `node --inspect-brk entry-point.js`.